# How to get the regex for my HTML?

Tags: regex

I want a regex for capturing latitude and longitude in some file say 52.5593266958818 and -1.9146537618027.

Comment: What you got so far?

Comment: Why would you use regex for this? Can't you directly access the elements in question? Or are you trying to process the HTML shown as text?

Comment: you're going to have to supply a **lot** more context to your question - and for the sake of everything sacred, I hope aren't embarking on path that could [summon "ZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: I am using some software actually and not directly reading the file. the software is asking for regex.

Comment: are you scraping somebodies website for data they don't want to share via conventional means?

Comment: hi you can treat this html as text only. and tell me how to use regex

Comment: Hi I can use access specifiers to capture those values. but my aim is not that. I have use regex in some software for scraping. thank you

Comment: @SunilKumar You need to update your actual question, not everyone reads the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will capture exactly those 2 numbers, no more no less.

```
/(52.5593266958818)|(-1.9146537618027)/g
52.5593266958818 // will capture
52.5593266958817 // will NOT capture
-1.9146537618027 // will capture
-1.9146537618026 // will NOT capture
```

Comment: beautiful and elegant

Comment: @chiliNUT I rate this answer 11/10. Exrtemely robust approach and future proofed.

Comment: this is very specific case I want general case. I want any value in that position.

Comment: @SunilKumar Then reword your question. Because that's what it seems you're asking right now.

Answer (score 0):

I used

`<div\sid="lat"\sstyle="display:\snone;">(.*)</div>`

for lat value and

`<div\sid="long"\sstyle="display:\snone;">(.*)</div>`

for long value

these are general regex match